# IIS - Application pool stopped when try to open the application in browser

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, iis-10

I have deployed the application in IIS server. code pusged to the directory and IIS server configuration are done using pipelines.
But when i try to run the application in browser, it makes the application pool stopped due to some issue. I was not able to fimnd out why this eetor is happened.
i tried to change the application pool--> identity option -->custom account -->setting my user name and paasword. when i try to give the user name and password it is working for fotsrt time. Again when i try to run the pipelines, the apllictaion pool is stopped.
can anyone help me to sove this issue
Thanks

Comment: If your web app fails frequently within seconds, IIS protects itself by disabling the application pool. So, before trying out anything else, contact the developers. If you are the developer, learn how to debug Windows process crash and exceptions. Nobody here can easily debug the issue for you without accessing the server and the source code.

Comment: If you don't know how to debug application and w3wp.exe crash issue, please use debug Diagnostic Tool v2 to collect dump file. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210